# Nodejs: How to prepare code for production environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

*I'm a beginner developing with Nodejs and React*.

Right now, I've got a first version of my web application which works correctly in development environment, but I'm trying to build a version for production environment but I've got this error

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

The scripts of my package.json are:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev-webpack": "webpack-dev-server --hot --mode development",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist",
    "dev": "npm run build-dev && cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --exec babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore ./src/client",
    "build-dev": "npm run clean && npm run compile-dev",
    "compile-dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack -d --config ./webpack.config.babel.js --progress",    
    "compile": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.babel.js --progress",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run compile",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./dist/assets/js/bundle.js"
  },
```

And I try to create the version for production environment with the command `npm run start`

I have been looking for information about the problem and it seems it's due because I have no Browserify my web application. But, I don't know how to do this correctly nor the steps to follow to do it correctly.

I am seeking a list of the steps required to build a correct version for production environment.

**Edit I:**

These are the static files generated with "build" script:

[image]

Comment: because react app will build files which needs to be statically served. your command  node bundle.js won't work as in node env you don't have document

Comment: How can I fix this problem?

Comment: npm run  build will produce the dist folder. Just run a static server inside the dist folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The React application is designed to be run **in a browser**.

When you run `dev-webpack` you are running an HTTP server and pointing a browser at it.

When you run `build` you are creating a static JavaScript file. You need to deploy it to a web server (along with the associated HTML document) and then point a browser at the HTML document.

You are currently trying to execute `bundle.js` with Node and not a browser.

Comment: Ok. So, If I don't understand bad, I've got to remove from "start" script node ./dist/assets/js/bundle.js because the statics files generated with "build" script will be served for a web server. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve your `index.html` file. You can use [serve](https://github.com/zeit/serve) to host the HTML file.